# Is there a universally accepted "nested element of" relation?

Tags: notation, set-theory, terminology

Let $f(a)=\{b,\{a\}\}$

Let $f^n$ indicate $n$ compositions of $f$.

Is there a (ideally universally accepted or standard) nested element relation $\prec$ of the obvious meaning such that $\forall n\in\Bbb N:a\prec f^n(a)$?  How is this normally treated?

Suppose there exists a limit $Y=\lim_{n\to\infty}f^n(a)$.  Does $\prec$ also cover $a\prec Y$?

Comment: You could write $a\in\mathrm{TC}(f^n(a))$ where $TC$ is the *transitive closure* operation.

Comment: Thanks @OscarCunningham that does the job perfectly. In the absence of any alternatives you could make that an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write $a\in\mathrm{TC}(f^n(a))$ where $\mathrm{TC}$ is the [transitive closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set#Transitive_closure) operation.